# laravel 5 with omnipay composer update issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, omnipay

after composer update i got following error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist' in D:\wamp\www\gastrodr\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 779
( ! ) ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist in D:\wamp\www\gastrodr\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 779
```

composer.json : which i get from ignited/laravel-omnipay from GIT repositary

```
{
    "name": "ignited/laravel-omnipay",
    "description": "Integerates Omnipay with Laravel and provides an easy configuration.",
    "keywords": ["omnipay", "payments", "laravel", "laravel5"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Alex Whiteside",
            "email": "alexwhiteside@ignitedlabs.com.au"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "~5",
        "omnipay/common": "2.3.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Ignited\\LaravelOmnipay": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

please advice me to fix this issue

=======

UPDATE

PaymentController - which used for paypal configuration

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Session;
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $data;
    public function getIndex()
    {   
        $this->data['product'] = 'Aurvana Platinum';
        $this->data['productImage'] = 'http://img.creative.com/images/products/large/pdt_21734.png.ashx?width=200';
        $this->data['price'] = '299.00';
        $this->data['currency'] = 'USD';
        $this->data['description'] = 'Flagship Over-the-ear Bluetooth® Headset with NFC';
        return View('hello', $this->data);
    }

    public function postPayment() 
    {
            $params = array(
                    'cancelUrl'     => 'http://localhost/cancel_order',
                    'returnUrl'     => 'http://localhost/payment_success', 
                    'name'      => Input::get('name'),
                    'description'   => Input::get('description'), 
                    'amount'    => Input::get('price'),
                    'currency'  => Input::get('currency')
            );

            Session::put('params', $params);
            Session::save();  

        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
        $gateway->setUsername('paypal account');
        $gateway->setPassword('paypal password');
        $gateway->setSignature('AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacASJcFfmT46nLMylZ2R-SV95AaVCq');
        $gateway->setTestMode(true);
        $response = $gateway->purchase($params)->send();
            if ($response->isSuccessful()) {

                // payment was successful: update database
                print_r($response);
        } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
```

Comment: What's the content of your Laravel's composer.json file?

Comment: @Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim  i have put it on my question check the code i post

Comment: It's the content of the composer.json file of the Omnipay package. Where's your composer.json of Laravel 5?

Comment: i replace that code with omni composer am i wrong ? @Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim  i remove laravel composer and add those lines there and did composer update

Comment: @Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim please advice how to do it... whta i did was did the changes on config/app.php as mentioned ading service provder and alias and replace composer... kindly pls advice

Comment: Change the contents of the composer.json file with the contents of my answer given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the contents of the composer.json file with these:

`{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "ignited/laravel-omnipay": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}`

And run `composer install` or `composer update`

Comment: Sumon Molla thanks im getting this error now on command line  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Class 'Ignited\LaravelOmnipay\LaravelOmnipayServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Remove the service provider you added on the app.php file. Then run the install and update. After that add the service provider and alias on the app.php file. Hope this will work.

Comment: ok it works may i know where to put \Ignited\LaravelOmnipay folder

Comment: You don't need to do anything or put any folder manually. Composer has already done that for you. You just add the service and alias on your config/app.php file. Then you are good to go :)

Comment: everything working almost fine now .. im getting this error now :( FatalErrorException in PaymentController.php line 34:
Class 'Omnipay\Omnipay' not found check my question i updated the controller